# ¿Donde fue el motivo de cierre "fuera del alcance definido en el centro de ayuda"?

Tags: soporte, cierre-de-preguntas, motivos-de-cierre

Me encontre que (aparentemente) desaparecio el motivo de cierre **"fuera del alcance definido en el centro de ayuda...."** - no recuerdo exactamente el texto pero era algo asi.

Ahora en su lugar aparece el motivo: Parece ser un problema que no se puede reproducir o un error tipografico.

Calculo que fue un error involuntario, por eso ¿Podemos tener ambos mensajes?

[image]

Comment: En esta pregunta se habla un poco sobre eso: http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/905/c%C3%B3mo-mejorar-el-motivo-de-cierre-fuera-de-alcance

Comment: @JuanPinzón la busque y no la encontre. DUP.